# Middle out fabletools reconciliation approach give problem with forecast function

Tags: r, forecasting, hierarchical-data, fabletools

I have a grouped time series with items and their category and I would like to make 6months sales forecasting.
I would like to o use intermediate level (category) to make base forecasting because the stagionality and trends maybe are better valued.
So i grouped my data for key, and i would like to use middle_out approch, the total sales use bottom up and single item are forected useing top down approach
I'm using fabletools middle_out function, but when i try to make forecast it doesn't work
this is my code:

```r
library(reshape)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(fable)
library(fpp2)
library(forecast)

#read data from csv
#example dataset
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
data_example <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2021-05-01"), "month"),
                  No_=sample(1800:1830, n, replace=TRUE),
                  Category=rep(LETTERS[1:3], n),
                  Quantity=sample(18:24, n, replace=TRUE))


sell_full <- data_example %>% mutate(Month=yearmonth(Date)) %>% group_by(No_,Category, Month) %>% summarise(Quant = sum(Quantity), .groups = 'keep')
sell_full <- na.omit(sell_full)

#data


#conversion to tsibble for forecastings

sell_full <- as_tsibble(sell_full, key=c(No_, Category), index=Month)
sell_full <- sell_full %>% aggregate_key((Category/No_), Quant= sum(Quant)) 
#sell_full<- filter(sell_full, !is.na(sell_full$Quant))

sell_full <- sell_full %>% fill_gaps(Quant=0, .full=TRUE)

fit <- sell_full %>%model(ets = ETS(Quant~ error("A") + trend("A") + season("A")))%>% middle_out(split=1)

fc <- forecast(fit, h = "6 months", level=1,lambda="auto")
```

if I put method="mo" in forecast method as documentation says it return this error

```
Error in meanf(object, h = h, level = level, fan = fan, lambda = lambda,  : 
  unused argument (method = "mo")
```

if i doesn't put method info in forecast it return this error:

```
<error/vctrs_error_ptype2>
Error in `vec_compare()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <agg_vec> and `..2` <double>.
---
Backtrace:
  1. generics::forecast(fit, h = "6 months", level = 1, lambda = "auto")
  2. forecast:::forecast.default(fit, h = "6 months", level = 1, lambda = "auto")
  3. forecast:::forecast.ts(object, ...)
  4. forecast::meanf(...)
  5. forecast::BoxCox(x, lambda)
  6. forecast::BoxCox.lambda(x, lower = -0.9)
  7. fabletools:::Ops.lst_mdl(x, 0)
 11. fabletools:::map2(e1, e2, .Generic)
 12. base::mapply(.f, .x, .y, MoreArgs = list(...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
 13. vctrs:::`<=.vctrs_vctr`(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]])
 14. vctrs::vec_compare(e1, e2)
```

The Documentions about it is very bad,
someone can help me?

UPDATE:
As someone suggest to me, I tried to remove some package, now my library are:

```
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(fable)
library(fpp3)
library(conflicted)
```

Now the error is changed. when I try to make forecast function I have this error:

```
Error in build_key_data_smat(key_data) : 
  argument "key_data" is missing, with no default
```

and if I put key_data = "Category" (Category is the split layer) the error is:

```
fc <- forecast(fit, h = "6 months",level=1,lambda="auto", key_data= "Category")
Error in -ncol(x) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Comment: Can you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput()`?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are loading packages that you don't need, which clash with other packages that you do need. Try without loading reshape, fpp2 or forecast.

Comment: `library(tidyverse) library(fpp3)` will load all the tidyverse and tidyverts packages. You can test for clashes with `library(conflicted)`, which is super handy.

Comment: @Isaiah  I add the new error string in the question's text, maybe forecast was the problem?
Maybe forecast package doesn't need key_data but it try to compare some wrong format.
It's better use forecast or fpp3?

Comment: @jrcalabrese I add a dataframe creation thath it's look like my data. now the code is reproducibile

Comment: Not sure why you have to supply key_data, given it's in the fit object, though. you do. The ncol error is because the code assumes that key_data is a vector, array, or data frame. I could do this via `x <- key_data(sell_full) |> unnest(cols = c(Category, No_, .rows))` and supply x as key_data.  This gets you further along, but a new error occurs. `Error in UseMethod("forecast") : 
  no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "c('agg_vec', 'vctrs_rcrd', 'vctrs_vctr')"` I didn't get any namespace errors. Sharing in case this gives someone an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(conflicted)
library(fpp3)
library(tidyverse)
n <- 6
data_example <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2021-05-01"), "month"),
                           No_ = sample(1800:1830, n, replace = TRUE),
                           Category = rep(LETTERS[1:3], n),
                           Quantity = sample(18:24, n, replace = TRUE))

sell_full <- data_example |> mutate(Month = yearmonth(Date)) |> group_by(No_,Category, Month) |> summarise(Quant = sum(Quantity), .groups = 'keep')
sell_full <- ungroup(sell_full)
sell_full <- as_tsibble(sell_full, key = c(No_, Category), index = Month)
sell_full <- sell_full %>% aggregate_key((Category/No_), Quant = sum(Quant))
sell_full <- sell_full %>% fill_gaps(Quant = 0, .full = TRUE)
fit <- sell_full %>% model(ets = ETS(Quant~ error("A") + trend("A")))

fc <- fabletools::forecast(fit, h = "6 months", lambda = "auto")
```

Thought I'd have a look at the code to generate sell_full.

Added an ungroup, took out the seasonal, and took out the `middle_out`. Runs now, and no longer asks for `key_value`. The `ungroup`, as it seemed that you were finished with the grouping. The seasonal as it was not supported by the data. The `middle out` as it would cause the prompt for `key_value`. Spent a bit of time on the `middle_out` leading to forecast asking for `key_value`, though, hence comment above.

This led me to try another way to do middle_out:

```
fit <- sell_full %>% model(ets = ETS(Quant~ error("A") + trend("A"))) |> reconcile(mo = middle_out(ets))
```

This runs fine. This idea came from [fpp3](https://otexts.com/fpp3/single-level.html#middle-out-approach) Hoping that this helps! :-)